# Make sure the first and second differential are continuous while using cubic spline interpolation

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm reading this [paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-37444-9_22#page-1). In this paper on page 286 they say they use cubic spline interpolation to ensure the existence of continuous first-order differential and second-order differentials.

I'm currently trying to do this in python. From this sentence I deduce they want to make sure the first  and second order derivative of the splines which are next to each other, are the same. My question is now, how can I do this with scipy ? I found this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html

Where there is a parameter `der` (The order of derivative of the spline to compute) . Is this the parameter which as to be 2 then ?

---

***A follow-up questio*n regarding this, they use the first-order differential points later on. Can I assume these are just the first-order derivates of each splines ? How is it possible to get these ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splines computed by `scipy.interpolate` that are of order `k` have continuous `1 ... k-1`:th derivatives. For your case order `k=3` would have continuous first and second derivative. You can check that this is true yourself via numerical differentiation of the spline:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
spl = interpolate.splrep(x, y, k=3)
xx = np.linspace(0, 10, 100000)
yy = interpolate.splev(xx, spl)
d1 = np.diff(yy) / np.diff(xx)
d2 = np.diff(d1) / np.diff(xx[1:])
d3 = np.diff(d2) / np.diff(xx[1:-1])
plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot(xx[1:], d1)
plt.title('first derivative')
plt.subplot(312)
plt.plot(xx[1:-1], d2)
plt.title('second derivative')
plt.subplot(313)
plt.plot(xx[2:-1], d3)
plt.title('third derivative')
plt.show()
```

The third derivative is the first one showing discontinuities.

Taking the second derivative can indeed be done directly via `splev(..., der=2)`.

(Without reading the paper, I can't comment on your second question.)

Comment: the paper: www.ojtwist.be/ibi.pdf :) , page 286 in the second half.